# Manifest no actualizado

Tags: android, flutter, manifest

Estoy usando il package google_maps_flutter actualizo mi manifest con la API key de google maps, pero obtengo siempre el siguiente error

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
    √  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
    Connecting to VM Service at ws://###.###.#.##/Z-FdiGlnXrA=/ws
    I/zzbz    (13090): Making Creator dynamically
    W/le.another_blo(13090): Unsupported class loader
    W/le.another_blo(13090): Unsupported class loader
    I/DynamiteModule(13090): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203115000
    I/DynamiteModule(13090): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203115000
    V/DynamiteModule(13090): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
    I/Google Maps Android API(13090): Google Play services client version: 12451000
    I/Google Maps Android API(13090): Google Play services package version: 220220040
    I/Google Maps Android API(13090): Google Play services maps renderer version(legacy): 203115000
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090): Failed to handle method call
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090): java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):6)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):1)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.l.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):24)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):7)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):2)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):18)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at dy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):4)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zza(Unknown Source:19)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source:13)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:18)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(Unknown Source:22)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source:26)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.onCreate(GoogleMapController.java:552)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.onStateChanged(FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.java:36)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.init(GoogleMapController.java:113)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapBuilder.build(GoogleMapBuilder.java:38)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapFactory.create(GoogleMapFactory.java:53)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createAndroidViewForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:151)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:296)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:320)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run(Unknown Source:12)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    E/MethodChannel#flutter/platform_views(13090):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
    I/bf      (13090): Successfully registered with Phenotype.
    E/flutter (13090): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml, null, java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):6)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):1)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.l.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):24)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):7)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapViewDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):2)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.aX(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):18)
    E/flutter (13090):  at dy.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@220220084@22.02.20 (150700-0):4)
    E/flutter (13090):  at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zza(Unknown Source:10)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf.zza(Unknown Source:19)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$zzb.createDelegate(Unknown Source:13)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaa(Unknown Source:18)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(Unknown Source:22)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source:26)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.onCreate(GoogleMapController.java:552)
    E/flutter (13090):  at androidx.lifecycle.FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.onStateChanged(FullLifecycleObserverAdapter.java:36)
    E/flutter (13090):  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
    E/flutter (13090):  at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:188)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapController.init(GoogleMapController.java:113)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapBuilder.build(GoogleMapBuilder.java:38)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemaps.GoogleMapFactory.create(GoogleMapFactory.java:53)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformViewsController$1.createAndroidViewForPlatformView(PlatformViewsController.java:151)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.create(PlatformViewsChannel.java:104)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.systemchannels.PlatformViewsChannel$1.onMethodCall(PlatformViewsChannel.java:59)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:296)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:320)
    E/flutter (13090):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.-$$Lambda$DartMessenger$TsixYUB5E6FpKhMtCSQVHKE89gQ.run(Unknown Source:12)
    E/flutter (13090):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    E/flutter (13090):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    E/flutter (13090):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    E/flutter (13090):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    E/flutter (13090):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    E/flutter (13090):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
    E/flutter (13090): )
    E/flutter (13090): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
    E/flutter (13090): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
    E/flutter (13090): 
    E/flutter (13090): #2      AndroidViewController.create
    E/flutter (13090): 
    E/flutter (13090):
```

Cuando consulto mi manifest esta perfectamente elaborado con su respectiva API_Key.
He probado desinstalando y reinstalando la app,
he probado haciendo un clean e reconstruyendo mi YAML y no cambia nada con respecto al error

Comment: Por favor muestra su AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar mayor información, en este caso el archivo manifest, revisa [ask],y no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio,  saludos.

Comment: Pude solucionar el problema!, parte del name-tag del package que estaba usando con flutter decia API_KEY y yo lo estaba sustituyendo con mi API KEY cuando era propio su nombre, entonces en el momento que corregi esto todo inicio a funcionar.